# How do I transfer data simultaneously using a single socket

Tags: java, sockets

I have a project that consists of:

- Java server: I accept the connection of N numbers of clients through multithreading.
- Client (c++): connects to the Java server.

The dilemma I'm having is how can I send information to the client (from Server) about X and at the same time while that happens make another request. To understand my question better I will give an example:

- example: Imagine that I am sending a file from the java server to the client in c++ and while this sending of bytes from the server is taking place, I want to send an echo to the client from the server and receive a response simultaneously while the sending of the file is happening. Is this possible?
- 2 example: Another case that I would like to address is what would happen if I am receiving bytes on the server from the client and I make another request (echo), so the same socket would be listening x2 (can i read bytes from the same socket simultaneously? What would happen then?):
  case 1: receiving bytes
  .case 2: listening to the echo

My solution so far has been to use Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor, which allows me to handle each "action" in order one by one. My goal is to be able to perform the actions asynchronously, so that I don't have to wait for another one to finish. How can I achieve this theoretically speaking?

Comment: If you want to use a single socket for multiple "data streams" (i.e. file, request, ...) at the same time, you have to implement some application layer protocol to implement multiplexing of multiple streams on top of a single byte stream. This is typically done by implementing a message semantic on top of the TCP byte stream where each message has some stream identifier so that both ends of the communication can find out which inner stream a specific message belongs too. Using multiple threads to write on the socket without such multiplexing protocol would result in mixed up corrupted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're anyway dealing with Java talking to C++, you might as well use something like Google Protocol Buffers to implement an application layer protocol (as Steffen Ullrich suggests), and definitely do not have multiple server threads sending data to a single client.

With GPB, you can define a set of messages, something like (pseudo GPB syntax)

```
message FileFragment
{
    string filename = 1,
    integer fragmentFilePosition = 2,
    bytes fragmentData = 3
}

message Echo
{
    integer echoNum = 1
}

message Protocol
{
    oneof
    {
        FileFragment fragment = 1,
        Echo echo = 2,
    }
}
```

With this, you'd create and send `Protocol` objects through the socket. The client receives those, and either stuffs the fragment data into a file at the position indicated, or deals with the echo.

There are other heterogenous serialisation technologies - ASN.1 is my preferred option, XML can be made to work if you can get good tools, JSON (though that might be a bit tricksie in C++?). I'd default to ASN.1, but GPB is free and enjoys excellent language support.

Java itself is sometimes a nuissance because (AFAIK) it doesn't support unsigned integer types, but as you're in control of both server and client source code (and therefore in control of the procotol between them and the schema that defines it), you can live with it. The nuissance comes if someone else has defined a protocol containing an unsigned 64bit integer type, which then cannot be easily handled in Java.

With Google Protocol Buffers, the wireformat is not self-demarcating, so if you just stuff serialised Protocol objects down the socket the client cannot tell when one ends and another begins. So you'll have to do that separately. A lot of people use something like ZeroMQ (which is message-orientated, not stream-orientated) for this purpose instead of a raw socket.

If you really wanted separate threads sending different `Protocol` objects through to the client, you'll need a way of guarding against both threads trying to access the socket at the same time (ZeroMQ sockets are not in themselves thread safe), a mutex of some sort.

Comment: Frankly, I gave the +1 mostly because you mentioned ASN.1 as your preferred option :)

Comment: @fdreger, ah a fellow devotee?! I've used it quite a lot, and I especially like it for how agile one can easily make a project, deep into development. I use it to define values, constraints, and of course PDUs (messages), and use those values in logic across the entire project. It's a wonderful way of making up one's mind about what an interface is at the very end of a project, rather than having to get it right at the beginning. I look around at projects that don't use ASN.1, or don't mimic its properties (like dBus's home-grown standard), and weep. So much stuff is only half thought through.

Comment: Those who don't know ASN.1 are bound to reinvent it :) (as it already has happened many times)